# Historic data on number of houses and number of households in UK?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for historic data (ideally going back to the 1920s, but whatever is available) on:

- the number of houses
- the number of households

in the UK.

I've been hunting on the ONS site and gov.uk without success.

Does anyone know where I could find this data?

Answer (score 2):

Did you find the [Live tables on Household Characteristics](https://www.gov.uk/government/statistical-data-sets/live-tables-on-household-characteristics) page? [Table 801: Tenure trend](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/11816/141491.xls) is an Excel spreadsheet which has the total number of households dating back to 1939 (not every year) and for 1918 it has percentages of owners and renters but not absolute numbers. ("Absolute", as the data is presented in thousands of households anyway.)

Files on the [Live tables on House Building](https://www.gov.uk/government/statistical-data-sets/live-tables-on-house-building) have data on the number of dwellings, although [the one I checked](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/405147/LiveTable209.ods) only dates back to 1969. These files are in ODS format.